How to get the width of available horizontal space of the sector for the donut pie chart?
I used the highcharts library to create a donut pie chart. I need to hide the label if the label is not able to fit the available space in the sector. I was trying to get the width, but since it's just a path with fill I'm not really sure how I can get the actual available width.
Donut pie chart
I tried to use arcLength but it's not the correct propery.
Demo - https://codepen.io/grafit_off/pen/bGPBBBY?editors=0010

The proper way is to use getBBox() method, so: this.point.graphic.getBBox().width
